# Why does a mutating method in a Swift protocol infinitely recurse unless only an extension method?

Tags: swift, protocols

I came across the following code in [SR-142 on bugs.swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-142#).

If a protocol has an extension method that's mutating, a class instance can call the mutating function without any problem.

```
// protocol definition
protocol P { }

extension P {
    mutating func m() { }
}

// class conforming to P
class C : P {
    // redeclare m() without the mutating qualifier
    func m() {
        // call protocol's default implementation
        var p: P = self 
        p.m()
    }
}

let c = C()
c.m()
```

If I make a small change to add the method to the protocol declaration:

```
protocol P {
  mutating func m()  // This is what I added.
}

extension P { 
  mutating func m() { } 
}

class C : P { 
  func m() { 
    var p: P = self 
    p.m() 
  }
}

let c = C() 
c.m()         // This one is calling itself indefinitely; why?
```

Why does `c.m()` keep calling itself again and again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your change in the second example, by including the `m` in the protocol definition, that instructs Swift to employ dynamic dispatch. So when you call `p.m()`, it dynamically determines whether the object has overridden the default implementation of the method. In this particular example, that results in the method recursively calling itself.

But in the first example, in the absence of the method being part of the protocol definition, Swift will employ static dispatch, and because `p` is of type `P`, it will call the `m` implementation in `P`.

---

By way of example, consider where the method is not part of the protocol definition (and therefore not in the “protocol witness table”):

```
protocol P {
    // func method()
}

extension P {
    func method() {
        print("Protocol default implementation")
    }
}

struct Foo: P {
    func method() {
        print(“Foo implementation")
    }
}
```

Because the `foo` is a `P` reference and because `method` is not part of the `P` definition, it excludes `method` from the protocol witness table and employs static dispatch. As a result the following will print “Protocol default implementation”:

```
let foo: P = Foo()
foo.method()              // Protocol default implementation
```

But if you change the protocol to explicitly include this method, leaving everything else the same, `method` will be included in the protocol witness table:

```
protocol P {
    func method()
}
```

Then the following will now print “Foo implementation”, because although the `foo` variable is of type `P`, it will dynamically determine whether the underlying type, `Foo`, has overridden that method:

```
let foo: P = Foo()
foo.method()              // Foo implementation
```

---

For more information on dynamic vs static dispatch, see WWDC 2016 video [Understanding Swift Performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/?time=1083).

Answer (score 1):

By declaring `m` in the protocol & providing implementation in your class, it over writes the default implementation.

But in the first example when you cast your class as protocol it will call protocol's default implementation because the implementation of the class is it own and not over writing any of the protocol's method